# How to keep a java project inter-operable between IDE's

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ide, intellij-idea, myeclipse

I tried to import an existing MyEclipse project in Eclipse, Galileo. Everything is fine except that I am not able to deploy the project with Tomcat6 plugin in Eclipse. I guess this is because the MyEclipse specific configuration of the project.

Is there a way to workaround for this? What is the best practice to keep your project inter-operable between different IDE's like Eclipse, MyEclipse and Intellij-Idea.

Answer (score 6):

Maven is the way to go. All popular Java IDEs have good support for Maven projects. Maven on the other side have plugins which create project files for those IDEs

Answer (score 2):

Each IDE has a different approach to things like deployment by plugins, so you might be better off doing your deploy through ant or maven, which can be called from the IDE.